# Magento 2 is really slow in localhost

Tags: php, magento2.2

I am using magento 2.2. I installed it on XAMPP, but it takes around 30 seconds to load the home page. Also on the product view page it takes too much time to add a product to the cart.

I enabled the `Use Flat Catalog Category` option, but nothing seems to affect the page loading speed significantly. How can I speed up magento 2? It's really difficult to develop magento site in this situation.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For Product detail page add to cart issue , change your host from 'localhost' to your pc ip address (ex. 192.168.1.11) by changing base_secure_url and base_unsecure_url in core_config_data